# SPFX Pagination and search from Listview control is not searching from whole item

Tags: sharepoint, spfx, pnp-js

Hi am using react based SPFX application, I have a List view grid control and search functionality is also enabled, So when I am searching from list view its giving correct result, But Client asked me to implement pagination from first page 10 items, I implemented SPFX pagination and its working fine paginating part but problem comes here when I am searching item from search box its giving result from first 10 page only instead of whole item, suppose there is status column "Approved" is more then 15 item but its searching from first page and when I am clicking on 2nd page then its providing result from the second page 10items. Is anyone have idea in which approach we can fetch the record from whole item using pagination, please let me know if you have any doubt, Thank you in advance.

Please help me for the solution

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.